# Why not Tracking visitors referral not working as expected in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working for an app by Laravel. In my apps, I am trying to track visitor referral by using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. Its working fine in most of the cases. However, in one referral url, its not working properly.

For example, if visitor comes from http://hadyhady00.sugardate.cpa.clicksure.com url, it detect that visitor comes from google.

Is there any solution to detect the right referral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will never could detect with 100% warranty. So what You could have is `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

- As you want to know the URL of the user, and not the address of the user, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` will not help
- `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` could seem OK, but actually is not :

  - The client doesn't have to send it (and it doesn't always do)
  - As it is sent by the client, it can be forged / faked Quite easily

**'HTTP_REFERER'**

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Naincy. 

I got your point. But I am wondering that, `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` cannot detect the visitor properly, but some other tacking system are able to detect perfectly. For example, google analytics. 

If the case, how they work than?

Comment: @tisuchi I havn't said its not possible....But as you using PHP, in that this is way that we can achieve and cannot rely on it 100%...If any other services like they able to achieve this then it depends on what tech they are using...

Comment: I see... 


Do you know any javascript plugin or code that I can use for detecting visitor referral details in accurate way?

Comment: use google analytics..... it will help you to give details of each use who visiting and which page and how many times.

Comment: Well... google analytics only tracking the visitor. In my site, most of the page are restricted from visitors. So, I want to know which visitor converted to users and each and every steps of this users. That's why, we cannot use google analytics.